An unexpected error occurred that requires a reload of this page
I am trying to run “code tunnel” on my laptop so that I can code remotely via my tablet.
Code tunnel seems to run fine on my laptop, and I can access https://vscode.dev/tunnel/{my-laptop-name} on my tablet. Yet I receive the error message “An unexpected error occurred that requires a reload of this page. The workbench failed to connect to the server (Error: Canceled)” in the VSCode screen on my tablet’s browser.
Could anyone please advise me on how to fix this?
Many thanks
Wolfram
I am running code tunnel on my laptop.
I accessed https://vscode.dev/tunnel/{my-laptop-name} on my tablet.

does https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/38410 look related?

Thanks for the link, starball! I am currently travelling without access to my laptop, but I will try what is outlined in that post once I’m back and then report back!
